# NodeJS in IIS with Reverse Proxy Cannot GET, but Works on Port 3000

Tags: node.js, express, iis

I have a node app running on Port 3000 and an IIS Reverse Proxy in place to serve this app via an IIS site per: https://travishorn.com/reverse-proxying-node-js-apps-on-windows-with-iis-acee318b6759

My IIS site is set to be Port 80 and has the following Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If I run the app from Port 3000 (http://localhost:3000), it executes the routes... However, if I load up the site via Port 80/IIS (http://localhost) it fails with a Cannot GET error for routes. It loads the default public page and the Swagger-UI at /api-docs without issue.

I suspect this is my web.config at play as my routes are within a sub directory. I thought that with the reverse proxy it would execute via the running node app but wonder if the Web.config needs adjusting for these routes.

An example of my structure is as follows:

```
node_modules
routes
    api1
    api2
server.js
```

My server.js is as follows:

```
// MODULES AND REQUIRES
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const swaggerJsDoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");
const objectMapper = require('object-mapper');
const cors = require('cors');

// Require Routes
var api1 = require('./routes/api1.js')
var api2 = require('./routes/api2.js')

// PORTS AND BASIC EXPRESS APP SETTINGS
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// CORS ALLOW ALL. NOTE IP RESTRICTIONS ARE IN PLACE
app.use(cors({
  origin: '*'
}));

// ignore request for FavIcon. so there is no error in browser
const ignoreFavicon = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.originalUrl.includes('favicon.ico')) {
      res.status(204).end();
  }
  next();
};

// Configure nonFeature
app.use(ignoreFavicon);

// Root Route - Serve Static File
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/client.html'));
});

// SWAGGER UI CONFIGURATION

// Primary Swagger Options
const options = {
  customCss: '.swagger-ui .topbar { display: none } .swagger-ui .scheme-container { display: none }'
};

// Custom Swagger Options: https://swagger.io/specification/#infoObject
const swaggerOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    info: {
      version: "2.0.0",
      title: "My App",
      description: "This page lists the available APIs within my app and allows you to test them.",
      contact: {
        name: "My Name"
      },
      servers: [{"url":"http://localhost:3000", "description": "Development server"}]
    }
  },
  // ['.routes/*.js'] Location for APIs
  apis: ["./routes/*.js"],
};

const swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerOptions);
app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs, options));


// ROUTES
  app.use('/api1', api1)
  app.use('/api2', api2)  

// APP LISTEN WITH SSL/HTTPS
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Any ideas why using the Reverse Proxy it is failing to load/find the routes?

**UPDATE:**

Per the recommendation to use the HTTP Platform Handler, I have installed it and have the following Web.config. OF NOTE: iisnode, Reverse Proxy with ARR, and HTTP Platform Handler all give me the same error on the routing. I am wondering if Node is not properly running or I need to move my solution (it is currently on the D: drive in a folder named MyApp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httppPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\node.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" arguments=".\server.js">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
                <environmentVariable name="NODE_ENV" value="Production" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I having been logging out and it keeps changing the port Node is running on instead of the Port 3000 I have declared. Its random port picking from what I can tell. This may explain why it can't "find" the app routes

Comment: People can save them from all the troubles if they use HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/the-rough-history-of-iis-httpplatformhandler/ (Why you shouldn't use ARR before you truly know what's required).

Comment: I had tried that as it was part of my iisnode configuration. Same issues arose. Do you have an example implementation of http platform handler?

Comment: I just tried the httpplatformhandler and it is still a Cannot Get error

Comment: You need to show your configuration portion for HttpPlatformHandler, either as part of this question, or a new one.

Comment: `"I having been logging out and it keeps changing the port Node is running on instead of the Port 3000 I have declared."` Please explain in detail what is going on. Your application is deployed on IIS and your request will be sent to the backend NodeJS server localhost:3000 through the reverse proxy server. Why does the random port appear?

Comment: I believe because it is hosted by IIS and the port 3000 is for development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this in your server.js:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

You use `process.env.PORT` to tell your application to take the PORT by reading the Environment Variable. You put the operator (||) just to make sure that if the PORT variable was not found, use the specified port 3000 instead.

You need to check the environment variables, the application may get the port number from the environment variables. I suggest you try using hardcoded values directly instead of getting them dynamically from environment variables.

If you hardcode it, you will always listen on port 3000, which may be just for you, or not, depending on your requirements and the requirements of the environment in which you're running your server.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. My environmental variable is set to 3000 as well. What is the normal way to host this in IIS as Node will grab an available port and it should find my routes. Do I need to do something special with my routes as it currently returns a “Cannot Get 404” error if I am on a random port. Why would the port affect the routes being found or not by IIS? Is that something I need to address in my web.config